# awk returning whitespace matches when comparing columns in csv

Tags: awk

I am trying to do a file comparison in awk but it seems to be returning all the lines instead of just the lines that match due to whitespace matching

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$6 in a{print $6}' file1.csv  fil2.csv
```

How do I instruct awk not to match the whitespaces?

I get something like the following:

```
cccs
dert

ssss


assak
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR && $2 {a[$2]; next}
           $6 in a       {print $6}' file1 file2
```

if you data file includes spaces and numerical fields, as commented below better to change the check from `$2` to `$2!="" && $2!~/[[:space:]]+/`

Comment: yes, right. added alternative that should handle 0 and white space.

Comment: I'm dealing with sensitive data so that's not an option.

Comment: I'm not sure how many options are available to create examples of whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Consider cases like $2=`<space>foo<space><space>bar` in file1 vs $6=`foo<space>bar<space>` in file2.

Here's how to robustly compare $6 in file2 against $2 of file1 ignoring whitespace differences, and only printing lines that do not have empty or all-whitespace key fields:

```
awk -F, '
{
    key = (NR==FNR ? $2 : $6)
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",key)
    gsub(/^ | $/,"",key)
}
key=="" { next }
NR==FNR { file1[key]; next }
key in file1
' file1 file2
```

If you want to make the comparison case-insensitive then add `key=tolower(key)` before the first `gsub()`. If you want to make it independent of punctuation add `gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"",key)` before the first `gsub()`. And so on...

The above is untested of course since no testable sample input/output was provided.